# How to align rotated text in the middle of a div

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I would like to vertical align rotated text in the middle of a 100% height div, like the image below.

So whenever the screen size changes the text stays in the middle of the div.

Anyone has a solution for this?

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/SVkPU/1/

```
.rotate-270 {
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform:rotate(270deg);
}

.left {
    float:left;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    height:50px;

}

.right {
    float:right;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me: 
http://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-text

also tried to use flexboxes. But as they are (still) not fully supported by all browsers especially (mobile) safari - on which it must work I go with a more supported approach.

Answer (score 8):

Well Buddy Add `text-align:center` of the `<div>` and then instead of rotating text at 90 deg! Rotate the `<div>` at 90 deg!

http://jsfiddle.net/KSAqR/1/

Comment: the problem is that it's not flexible anymore. And they should be floated to the sides like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SVkPU/2/
I only can't get the text centered in the div.